# Does Create 2 have a built in optical interface (IR remote) using the Open Interface Spec

Tags: serial

I was starting to work on the Arduino interface (and Raspberry Pi) using the USB serial cable for the Create 2 , as a baseline to build other outer loop controls. 
My wife asked me why I would do that, and she handed me her Roomba remote control. It worked ! 
Well, the Roomba IR remote only transmits, and the functions are only a small subset of the Open Interface Spec. 
Rather than jumping into another Arduino build side project so I can decode the Roomba IR remote and waste alot of time, and tear apart the Create 2, ( I also assume the schematics are proprietary) ......here are my questions.....

Does the Create 2 hardware include a separate IR receiver and transmitter that works in parallel with the serial interface (so I can optically isolate the control signals and do away with the serial cable. )?
Does the Create 2 use IR sensors multiplexed to the home base for receiving the IR remote commands ?

Thanks for any info on a serial IR interface possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

RoanokeRoboticsClub whoop whoop! I'm based in the Roanoke area!

For your question, I would direct you to the [Create2 Open Interface spec](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/create_2_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf), pages 24-26, and ask if that's enough to answer your question and, if not, to please *edit your question* to include more specifics of what you're trying to do and why the information in the spec is insufficient.

To clarify, too, it looks like Packet IDs 17, 52, and 53,

> ...identifies the 8-bit IR character currently being received by [the respective sensor]. A value of 0 indicates that no character is being received. These characters include those sent by the Roomba Remote, Dock, Virtual Walls, Create robots using the Send-IR command, **and user-created devices.**

Emphasis added to highlight that you can make your own IR device and, presumably, your own values.

For compatibility, I would treat 0 and the character values listed in the table on pages 25-26 as "reserved" characters, and then you're free to use any other value, without "collision," to signal/flag your code to do whatever you want.